# event key code for ampersand?

Tags: javascript, key, keycode

I am trying to find the keycode for ampersand and underscore. I should not allow my users to allow to enter ampersands and underscores. I was taking a look at one list, and it mentions 55 as the keycode for both 7 & ampersand, and another list says that 55 is the keycode for 7. So if I return false when my user hits the keycode 55, I am disallowing the user from using 7, which isn't the requirement. How do I find the keycodes for ampersand and underscore?

I just tried with 55, but it only is giving me the alert for 7 not with ampersand!

```
function noenter(e)
{
    evt = e || window.event;
    var keyPressed = evt.which || evt.keyCode;

    if(keyPressed==13)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(evt.shiftKey && keyPressed===55)
//  else if(keyPressed==59 || keyPressed==38 || keyPressed==58 || keyPressed==95)
    {
        alert("no special characters");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `keypress` event and test directly for the character as follows. Don't mess with key codes: they will vary between different keyboard types and cultures. Character codes won't.

```
var el = document.getElementById("your_input");

el.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    if (charStr == "&" || charStr == "_") {
        alert(charStr);
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Since I need to press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>-<kbd> for `_`, `String.fromCharCode(charCode)` returns an ["unprintable character"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278271/what-is-the-result-of-string-fromcharcode17), is there a way to tackle this problem for listening to underscores?

Comment: @SajibAcharya: You need to do this in the `keypress` event. In `keydown` or `keyup` you get key codes rather than character codes.

Comment: keypress event does not fire on android chrome browser. Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

Check if the shift key is down:

```
//e = Event
(e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 55) //returns true if Shift-7 is pressed
```

Comment: hey digital, it is working for me. I will edit my post, and put the code, could you take a look if I am making a mistake.

Comment: I don't think this is an universal solution, since `keyCode`s tend to be different for different browsers, platforms, keyboards, etc.

Answer (score 0):

ok got it! it is 38! sorry for putting up this question!

Comment: umm ... I know it's almost 7 years ago, but this shouldn't be in the answer section. :D

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it using the Unicode Key Identifier. Below is my implementation with jQuery:

```
function parseKey(key) {
    return parseInt(key.substring(2), 10);
}

$inputs.bind('keydown', function(e) {
    var c=parseKey(e.originalEvent.keyIdentifier);
    //allow only numbers and backspace
    if ((c<30 || c>39) && e.which!=8)
        e.preventDefault();
    if (e.which == 13)
        $(this).blur();
});
```