# What is the result of String.fromCharCode(17)?

Tags: javascript

I am confused about this static method. When using the 17 char code (control key), I can't find a way to compare it to anything.

Chrome console:

[image: String.fromCharCode(17)]

It looks like a regular empty string.

The [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) says

> This method returns a string and not a String object.

so I was thinking that

`String.fromCharCode(17) === ""` would return true. But it returns false.
Why?

- `typeof(String.fromCharCode(17))` returns "string"
- `String.fromCharCode(17) === null` returns false
- `String.fromCharCode(17) === undefined` returns false
- Also, just to be sure, I did `String.fromCharCode(17) === new String()` and it returned false too...

I don't understand...

Comment: char code 17 is [Ctrl](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) and can't be cout-ed I suppose.

Comment: Since you know 17 represents the control key, what makes you think it should print anything?

Comment: @BoltClock I don't expect it to print anything. I just expect "anything" to be consistent accross its representations :)

Comment: @Sebas If you want consistency, front-end web development may not be your flavour ;)

Comment: It seems to only print ASCII chars for parameter values `33` - `126`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) for `String.fromCharCode()` quote is incomplete,

> returns a string created by using the specified sequence of Unicode values.

In this case, a non-printable character - ASCII 17 - or Device Control 1.

Answer (score 2):

> so I was thinking that `String.fromCharCode(17) === ""` would return `true`. But it returns `false`. Why?

`String.fromCharCode(17)` returns *device control 1*, which seems to be an unprintable character. The reason it fails the condition is because it is *not* an empty string.

`String.fromCharCode(17) === String.fromCharCode(17)` would return `true`.

Comment: You mean it is a console behavior issue? I would think the unprintable character would translate to something if its type is actually a string

Comment: Nope. It's normal JavaScript behaviour. The two strings aren't equivalent, firstly because they have different lengths.

Comment: @Sebas: No, that's why it's called "unprintable".

Comment: to me there's a contradiction. The console should show a symbol dedicated to unprintable characters, not an empty string. Actually I see above that IE does show something else...

Comment: @Sebas How do you print ' '? What about ASCII-8 (Backspace)?

Comment: Hi @ElliottFrisch, backspace is not a string... it should return that same unprintable symbol I guess...

Answer (score 2):

When I tried it's showing `""` (non-printing character) so, it's not an empty string. See below image for a proof:

[image]

Which is why `String.fromCharCode(17) === ""` would return false.

Comment: That's the this font set doesn't include that glyph glyph.

Answer (score 1):

*String.fromCharCode() method returns a string created by using the specified sequence of Unicode values.* KeyChar 17 actually represents the CTR key of our keyboard. So when you are writing

```
String.fromCharCode(17) ,
```

*It actually representing characters that cannot be represented into one 16-bit number*. hence, its not empty string , something that can't be displayed as it takes more than one 16-bit numbers unicode values.